# Realtek ethernet driver compilation errors - kernel 5.3 - Ubuntu 18.04

Tags: networking, drivers, kernel, realtek

Any clues on how to get a working driver for Realtek 8168?

Intel Wireless functions normally, however, Realtek wired does not since the driver compile fails.

Compilation errors:

```
    DKMS make.log for r8168-8.045.08 for kernel 5.3.0-22-generic (x86_64)
Thu Nov 14 11:16:00 CET 2019
make: Entering directory '/usr/src/linux-headers-5.3.0-22-generic'
  CC [M]  /var/lib/dkms/r8168/8.045.08/build/r8168_n.o
  CC [M]  /var/lib/dkms/r8168/8.045.08/build/r8168_asf.o
  CC [M]  /var/lib/dkms/r8168/8.045.08/build/rtl_eeprom.o
  CC [M]  /var/lib/dkms/r8168/8.045.08/build/rtltool.o
/var/lib/dkms/r8168/8.045.08/build/r8168_n.c: In function ‘rtl8168_down’:
/var/lib/dkms/r8168/8.045.08/build/r8168_n.c:27919:9: error: implicit declaration of function ‘synchronize_sched’; did you mean ‘synchronize_net’? [-Werror=implicit-function-declaration]
         synchronize_sched();  /* FIXME: should this be synchronize_irq()? */
         ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
         synchronize_net
cc1: some warnings being treated as errors
scripts/Makefile.build:288: recipe for target '/var/lib/dkms/r8168/8.045.08/build/r8168_n.o' failed
make[1]: *** [/var/lib/dkms/r8168/8.045.08/build/r8168_n.o] Error 1
Makefile:1655: recipe for target '_module_/var/lib/dkms/r8168/8.045.08/build' failed
make: *** [_module_/var/lib/dkms/r8168/8.045.08/build] Error 2
make: Leaving directory '/usr/src/linux-headers-5.3.0-22-generic'
```

**Output from lshw...**
sudo lshw -C network

```
  *-network                 
       description: Wireless interface
       product: Wireless 7260
       vendor: Intel Corporation
       physical id: 0
       bus info: pci@0000:02:00.0
       logical name: wlp2s0
       version: 6b
       serial: 7c:7a:91:26:92:15
       width: 64 bits
       clock: 33MHz
       capabilities: pm msi pciexpress bus_master cap_list ethernet physical wireless
       configuration: broadcast=yes driver=iwlwifi driverversion=5.3.0-22-generic firmware=17.3216344376.0 ip=192.168.18.40 latency=0 link=yes multicast=yes wireless=IEEE 802.11
       resources: irq:47 memory:f7d00000-f7d01fff


  *-network UNCLAIMED
       description: Ethernet controller
       product: RTL8111/8168/8411 PCI Express Gigabit Ethernet Controller
       vendor: Realtek Semiconductor Co., Ltd.
       physical id: 0
       bus info: pci@0000:03:00.0
       version: 0c
       width: 64 bits
       clock: 33MHz
       capabilities: pm msi pciexpress msix vpd bus_master cap_list
       configuration: latency=0
       resources: ioport:e000(size=256) memory:f7c00000-f7c00fff memory:f0000000-f0003fff

sudo dpkg -l | grep r8168; dkms status

rc  r8168-dkms                                    8.045.08-2                                             all          dkms source for the r8168 network driver
v4l2loopback, 0.10.0, 5.3.0-20-generic, x86_64: installed
v4l2loopback, 0.10.0, 5.3.0-22-generic, x86_64: installed
```

Comment: Why are you trying to install that driver? Does the NIC work OK without it. The driver is required in case a hardware revision isn't well supported by Linux kernel yet. It is unlikely to be the case for the 5.3 kernel.

Comment: Probably you blacklisted the relevant module.

Comment: What does `sudo modprobe r8169` output?

Comment: Please [edit] your question and add output of `dpkg -l | grep r8168; dkms status`.

Answer (score 0):

This means that the driver version is incompatible with the 5.3 Linux kernel.

But most likely you don't need this driver at all, because the `r8169` kernel module is supposed to drive the network adapter well.

You can remove this driver by

```
sudo apt remove r8168-dkms
```

if it was installed using `apt`.

After you remove this moduke, reboot and your NIC should ve driven by `r8169`.

Comment: These are errors encountered during a routine update.  I'm not arbitrarily trying to install the driver.

Comment: So remove the driver. It doesn't build, but the network adapter works without it. It proves that you don't need it.

Comment: I have just done that.  The salient point is, and I neglected to point this out, is that wifi functions normally but the wired connection does not.  That's the reason I'm pursuing a fix.

Comment: Please add output of `grep r8169 /etc/modprobe.d/*` and `lspci -knn | grep Eth -A3`

Comment: Run `sudo modprobe r8169`. The wired adapter should work.

Comment: /etc/modprobe.d/r8168-dkms.conf:# map the specific PCI IDs instead of blacklisting the whole r8169 module
/etc/modprobe.d/r8168-dkms.conf:# to blacklist the whole r8169 module
/etc/modprobe.d/r8168-dkms.conf:#blacklist r8169
03:00.0 Ethernet controller [0200]: Realtek Semiconductor Co., Ltd. RTL8111/8168/8411 PCI Express Gigabit Ethernet Controller [10ec:8168] (rev 0c)
 Subsystem: Samsung Electronics Co Ltd RTL8111/8168/8411 PCI Express Gigabit Ethernet Controller [144d:c0ef]
 Kernel driver in use: r8169
 Kernel modules: r8168

Comment: I removed the blacklist entry.  Wired is working now.  I'll assume everything is OK

Comment: Thanks, for your help!

Comment: If you ran `sudo apt remove r8168-dkms` the blacklist should be removed too.

Comment: Actually, I added that entry myself when I was trying to fix the problem based on other posts dealing with similar issues.  So, maybe the apt uninstall would not catch that.

Comment: So, after I rebooted, I see that the problem resurfaces.  I think manually doing the modprobe is what got it working but that isn't happening otherwise.

Comment: Which problem? You need to remove `r8168` completely from DKMS. Did you remove `/etc/modprobe.d/r8168-dkms.conf` file?

Comment: The problem of wired not working. No, I just did the apt remove.  I'll look at that now.

Comment: OK, I manually removed /etc/modprobe.d/r8168-dkms.conf, rebooted, and everything is working so far.  Thanks.

Comment: It looks OK now.